# How can I see variable values within an inlinescript script block executed within an Azure runbook?

Tags: powershell, runbook

This has to be something completely obvious so if it is forgive me. I have dug through posts, articles, etc for the better part of the day and am hoping someone can shed some light this.

The problem is my DataSet Fill is failing within an inlinescript script block. I have been looking to see how to view the contents of my $connectionstring, $query, and $cmd variables within this inlinescript script block.
 
I have defined a connection string and query variable.  I can do a $conn.Open() and it doesn't fail.  I have passed the connection and query variables into my SQLCommand object:

```
 $cmd = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $conn)
```

I create the DataSet and DataAdaptor objects:

```
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
       $da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
```

When executing the following:

```
 try {
    [void]$da.Fill($ds)
    }
    catch {
    Write-Error "Not able to fill dataset for list of customers!"
    }
```

The catch/error branch is taken.

My belief is that there are no results being returned so $cmd is empty resulting in the Fill error.  Being in a runbook none of the commands that send output to the console are valid.  Being able to capture the contents of $connectionstring, $query, and $cmd variables  would be huge.

BTW, the code within $query executes as expected within SSMS.

Without the try-catch statement, this is the error that appears:

```
 CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the try-catch statement, get the exact error message, and if that doesn't help, post it here.

Comment: CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

 

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: from the error, it looks like $da isn't properly retrieving what you want it to.

Comment: Try outputting $da right after you create it, and perhaps check if $cmd works too.

Comment: @Maxima Franchot - Poorly formed query on might hence the failure.  Thank you. +1 for solution.